Two Umbrella Policies
I have a 6 million dollar umbrella policy through my current insurance company. I do not want to switch insurance companies and  they will not increase the limit on my umbrella. I want a larger umbrella policy so I plan to buy a second umbrella policy.
Let say the second policy is for 4 million. That should give me a total of 10 million dollars of coverage in the case I am sued. Is there anything I am missing?

It all depends on how the insurance contracts are written.  However, most policies don't have double coverage and there would be a fight over which one has to pay first.  Often times they agree to pay half each.  The worst thing you would want is to be sued for 7 million and have your current company pay 4 and the new company pay 2 (which is a likely scenario).
You may be approaching the limits of what an umbrella policy's purpose.  It might be time to setup some trusts/LLCs and an lawyer can help with that.  It would seem that the source of your wealth would determine the kind of protection you should acquire.  Also state and local tort and inheritance laws will come into play.
The best thing to do is to talk to a good estate planning lawyer, not some "ham and egger", but someone who is well respected.  Given the size of your holdings, being frugal is not advised.
Several people I know cease their umbrella coverage at 1 million despite having assets over that amount.  They figure that is good enough, and in many cases that is that is based on advice from a lawyer.

"your current company pay 4 and the new company pay 2" -- can you explain further how this would happen (where do the numbers come from)?

The numbers come from agreement between the insurers of how their policies interact, who is the primary versus secondary insurer, and so on. That's assuming that you can get a second umbrella policy at all, without jeopardizing the first. Frankly, if I was an insurance broker, I would look at a request for two stacked umbrella policies as almost being a declaration that the individual intends to try to commit fraud. I believe there are better ways to do what you are trying to do, but as Pete said, you need expert advice, not the spare time opinions of a bunch of randos on the internet.

@keshlam You replied to my comment but did not @ me, and you seem to have me confused with OP ("what you are trying to do..."). Pete B. said the $4M + $2M breakdown was "a likely scenario". I take that to mean there is a specific, common set of policy terms that would lead to that outcome given OP's scenario. It seemed related to the previous remark "they agree to pay half each". I am just asking what calculation Pete B. did to conclude that a $7M judgment would result in the $6M policy paying $4M and the $4M policy paying $2M

@nanoman it doesn't matter and the math seems obvious to me.  Half each basically.  So few people have this kind of wealth that this very specialized.  The 10 million mark puts one in the top 1% of households for wealth.

@PeteB. The math isn't obvious to me, which is why I asked. If OP is found liable for $7M, "half each" sounds to me like each policy would pay $3.5M. But you posited $4M+$2M, with OP left holding the bag for the remaining $1M (which I assume is why you called it "the worst thing you would want"). Can you please spell out the math that leads to $1M of the $7M being uncovered, rather than just saying it's obvious?
